# Mongo group inside $addToSet

Tags: mongodb

I have the following set of objects:

```
 [
    {
      id: 1,
      clientId: 1,
      cost: 200
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      clientId: 2,
      cost: 500
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      clientId: 2,
      cost: 800
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      clientId: 1,
      cost: 600
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      clientId: 2,
      cost: 100
    }
]
```

And I made a group of that with:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
   {
     '$group': {
        '_id': '$id',
        'clients': {
           '$addToSet': {
              'id': '$clientId',
              'cost': '$cost'
            }
        }
      }
   }
)
```

So I obteined the following:

```
[
    {
        '_id': 1,
        'clients': [
            {
                id: 1,
                cost: 200
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                cost: 500
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                cost: 800
            }
        ],
        '_id': 2,
        'clients': [
            {
                id: 1,
                cost: 600
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                cost: 100
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

As you can see in the array of clients of the first value, I have 2 repeated and what I want is to have 1 with the cost added. So instead of have:

```
'clients': [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    cost: 200
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    cost: 500
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    cost: 800
                }
            ]
```

I need:

```
'clients': [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    cost: 200
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    cost: 1300
                }
            ]
```

So my question is: how can I do that? Because $addToSet nor $push allow $sum.

Comment: How did you get those values in `clients`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [aggregation operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) to get expected output like following:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    "$group": {
    "_id": {
        "mainId": "$id",
        "client": "$clientId"
    },
    "cost": {
        "$sum": "$cost"
    }
    }
}, {
    "$project": {
    "mainId": "$_id.mainId",
    "clients": {
        "clientId": "$_id.client",
        "cost": "$cost"
    },
    "_id": 0
    }
}, {
    "$group": {
    "_id": "$mainId",
    "clients": {
        "$push": "$clients"
    }
    }
})
```